# Null static field even after instantiating

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have a class with static field and static setter function to set its value.

```
class Intermediate{
  private static Type myObject=null;
  public static void setIntermediate(Type ob){
     myObject=ob;
  }

  public static String  getValue(){
      if(myObject!=null)
        return myObject.getValue();
      else
        return "";   // <== always returning this value

  }


}
```

`Intermediate.getValue()` is called by a native code cpp.

In my main activity I am initiating the value as

```
class myActivity extends Activity{
    void  onCreate(){
        Intermediate.setIntermediate(new subType()); 
    }    
}
```

Here `subType` is a subclass of the `Type` class.

In native side I am calling `getValue()` of Intermediate class and its myObject is always `null`;

Comment: Either `onCreate` is not being called or you should set `myObject` to `volatile`.

Comment: onCreate is setting called.. Also the set method.. But my variable is volatile.

Comment: Will making it volatile  solve this problem??

Comment: If you are seeing an inter-thread cacheing issue then making it `volatile` should fix the problem. If your problem is elsewhere then it will not.

Comment: Use a debugger and check the value of myObject at the end of the call to setIntermediate.

Comment: What happens if you check the object in your `Java`-code? Is it output correctly?

Comment: You might want to add the definitions of `Type` and `subType`

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon using Yes the variable is accessed using two different thread. But making it volatile doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: See @DJClayworth suggestion.

Comment: Yes I checked in first thread its comming correct and showing the reference of the option which i have set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren't initializing the string property of the subType in your code. Your onCreate() method is doing this:

```
new subType()
```

So when Intermediate.getValue() is called you are hitting this line

```
return myObject.getValue();
```

Your can fix this by doing this instead

```
void  onCreate(){
    Type t = new subType();
    t.setValue("whatever string you want");
    Intermediate.setIntermediate(t); 
}
```